# Solving the integration problem by use of fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

In one test the question said $$f(x,t)=\int_{0}^{g(x,t)} e^{-u^2} du$$

Now how I can calculate $\partial^2f/\partial t^2$ ?

I have this idea:
$$\int_{0}^{g(x,t)} e^{-u^2} du=F(g(x,t))-F(0)$$

When $F$ is the primitive function of $\int e^{-u^2} du$ and then use the chain rule and FTC.
Is this approach common? What's your idea?

I should say that $g(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2kt}}$ and so I had messy computations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{0}^{g(x,t)} e^{-u^2} du=e^{-g^2(x,t)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,t)\ ,
$$
where one uses the fundamental theorem of calculus $\frac{d}{dz}\int_0^z dt\ h(t)=h(z).$

Taking a second derivative (using the product rule)
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}f(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[e^{-g^2(x,t)}]
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(x,t)+e^{-g^2(x,t)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}g(x,t)\ ,
$$
and I'm sure you can take it from here (use the chain rule for the first factor).